# Why is this sword more valuable than an objectively better weapon?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Less damage, less armor piercing effect (left) - but why does the better steel sword (right) have less value?

[image]

Comment: I don't have proof of this, but it's possible that it could be relative to the weight, too.  You might compare a few items, and see if that holds true.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is: rarity.

Witcher weapons and armour are rare and very few, if any, blacksmiths know how to craft them. In universe supply and demand means that the value of Witcher equipment is higher than common equipment such as the other sword you have used for comparison, even if the other equipment is better.

Comment: Even despite the Witcher sword being listed as a "Common Item" and the Velen a "Master Item"? Looks like the descriptions are out of sync with the lore.

Comment: From memory the item classification refers to the required skill level for a blacksmith to craft the item. So a common item could be crafted by any smith if you, or they, have the diagram. To craft a Master item you need to find a Master level blacksmith.

Comment: I guess it's the same as in real life. If an item is hard to find then one will have greater value, and it also depends of with what it's done.
Like if you're going to put diamonds on a sword it's not going to do more damages but will cost more.